# Multiple Select for nested attributes in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :admin_permissions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin_permissions
end
```

View:

```
= ep.fields_for :department, dept_object do |dept|
    = dept.fields_for :admin_permissions, @user.admin_permissions.new(department: dept.object) do |ap|
      = ap.collection_select :permission_type, AdminPermission.permission_types.map{ |dp| [dp.first, dp.first.humanize] }, :first, :second, {}, { :multiple => true, class: 'form-control' }
```

but in the params after the submit button is pressed, the params look like this:

```
"department_attributes"=>
  {"company_id"=>"2",
   "name"=>"",
   "admin_permissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"permission_type"=>["", "human_resource"]}}},
```

instead of

```
"department_attributes"=>
  {"company_id"=>"2",
   "name"=>"",
   "admin_permissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"permission_type"=>"hr"}, "1" => {"permission_type" => "manager"}}}
```

how can i achieve this with multiple select? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct, but you could try to remove the :multiple out of the brackets

`ap.collection_select :permission_type, AdminPermission.permission_types.map{ |dp| [dp.first, dp.first.humanize] }, :first, :second, {}, :multiple => true`

But the results will always be in the form

`"admin_permissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"permission_type"=>["", "human_resource", "management"]}}}`

They will not have each their own id, but will be passed as a list.

Comment: Will that create separate objects?

Comment: No, I guess you'll have to do the update_attribute calls in the controller yourself. But I'm not sure that would work with your notation either. Of what type is the relation to the nested attributes? You do want to create a new one for each of the passed selects and not just pass and association like for has_and_belongs_to_many relations, right?